# Why variable is blank when using nested environments with tikz and figure

Tags: environments

I have the following document setup:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\newenvironment{foo}{
  \newcommand\bara{}
  \newcommand\barb[1]{
    \renewcommand\bara{##1}
    \typeout{FIRST}
    \typeout{##1}{\bara}
  }

  \newenvironment{baz}{
    \begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}{scale=1}
  }{
    \typeout{SECOND}
    \typeout{\bara}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \typeout{\bara}
    \caption{\bara}
    \end{figure}
  }
}{}

\begin{foo}
  \begin{baz}
    \bara{abc}
  \end{baz}
\end{foo}

\end{document}
```

It logs:

```
SECOND
[blank]
```

The last line is blank, and the FIRST stuff is missing. (And the caption is blank in the PDF).

I am new to latex and am not sure how to go about debugging this beyond putting the `\typeout` statements in the document.

Wondering why it doesn't log:

```
FIRST
abc
SECOND
abc
abc
```

Comment: I don't have `makeatletter` or `makeatother` at all, not sure what those do.

Comment: With the current code you're using `\bar` which has a standard definition. Please fix.

Comment: as seen in comments here, questions are very confusing if they do not have a complete test document (as provided in the answer)

Comment: You should have `\barb` in the middle of those environments, not `\bara`. Anyway, you're setting the value of `\bara` inside a `tikzpicture` environment and, by rule, it is lost as soon as the environment ends.

Comment: @LancePollard Without going into categorycodes and such then, in short, any macro between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` can contain the at `@` character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test code should be

```
\begin{foo}
  \begin{baz}
    \barb{abc}
  \end{baz}
\end{foo}
```

because it's `\barb` that sets the value of `\bara`.

Where's the problem? The `baz` environment opens a `tikzpicture` environment which forms a group; the `\barb{abc}` declaration is issued inside this `tikzpicture` so it's no longer available when the environment ends.

Depending on your needs, this could be solved by setting `\bara` *globally*; it's also possible to smuggle values one level up, with some lower level programming, if needed.

The level of generality of the question doesn't allow for suggesting a choice.

Answer (score 0):

This MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{foo}%
{%
%
  \newcommand\@bar{}%
  \renewcommand\bar[1]{%
    \renewcommand\@bar{##1}%
    \typeout{FIRST}%
    \typeout{##1}{\@bar}%
  }%
%
  \newenvironment{baz}%
  {%
  }%
  {%
    \typeout{SECOND}%
    \typeout{\@bar}%
  }%
}%
{}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{foo}
  \begin{baz}
    \bar{abc}
  \end{baz}
\end{foo}
\end{document}
```

Seems to produce the correct output/log

```
% latex tmp.tex
[snip]
FIRST
abc
SECOND
abc
[snip]
Output written on tmp.pdf (1 page, 11670 bytes).
Transcript written on tmp.log.
```

Comment: not sure what you changed

Comment: Nothing.. That's the point. The correct output is produced with the exact same code that you posted. So I am not sure what the problem is given that you haven't provided a MWE.

Comment: I don't have `makeatletter` or `makeatother` if that matters

Comment: I'm adding those two to my .cls file and getting `! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.`

Comment: Even if I remove the `@` in the commands it is blank.

Comment: Ah, for some reason if I move the `\typeout{SECOND}%...` before a `\end{tikzpicture}` in my document it works :|.

Comment: ;( `! Undefined control sequence.`

Comment: I updated the question with an example demonstrating the error for real now.